# SQL Query - Filter valid & invalid data by few columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table data shown as below.

[image]

You can generate the same by running following script

```html
DECLARE @Temp Table
(
 Id varchar(50),
 Name varchar(50),
 ProductId varchar(50)
)
insert into @Temp values('1','O1','P1');
insert into @Temp values('1','O1','P2');
insert into @Temp values('2','O1','P1');
insert into @Temp values('3','O1','P3');
insert into @Temp values('4','O1','P4');
insert into @Temp values('5','O1','P4');
insert into @Temp values('6','O1','P6')
select * from @Temp
```

I want two different out put based on below condition

1) Either Id or ProductId are not same

[image]

2) Either Id or ProductId are same

[image]

What is the best way to do this operation? Appreciate running code for the same so my input can be validate on the same?

Comment: For your first output, I would have expected `P2`, `P3` and `P6` to appear.  Why is `P2` not in the result set?  Your quesiton is unclear.

Comment: I thought that at first @TimBiegeleisen . it's because the first 2 rows share the same value for `ID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using similar approach from Larnu's comment, in place of CTE using Temp tale to store the result so it can be reusable in two query.

```html
DECLARE @TempCount Table
(
 Id varchar(50),
 Name varchar(50),
 ProductId varchar(50),
 IdCount int,
 ProductCount int
)


insert into @TempCount
    SELECT Id,
           [Name],
           ProductId,
           COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS IDCount,
           COUNT(ProductId) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId) AS ProductCount
    FROM @Temp
 
--Get the unique records
SELECT *
FROM @TempCount
WHERE IDCount = 1 AND ProductCount = 1;

--Get the duplicate records
SELECT *
FROM @TempCount
WHERE IDCount > 1 OR ProductCount > 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

I *think* this is what you are after:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Id,
           [Name],
           ProductId,
           COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS IDCount,
           COUNT(ProductId) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId) AS ProductCount
    FROM @Temp)
SELECT Id,
       [Name],
       ProductId
FROM CTE
WHERE IDCount = 1 AND ProductCount = 1;
```

This, at least, returns the results you are after:

```
Id  Name ProductId
--- ---- ---------
3   O1   P3
6   O1   P6
```

You should easily be able to change the `WHERE` to get the other result; if you can't this means you don't understand the above code and therefore you should be asking how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

First Query

```
Select * from @Temp
where Id in (
    select Id from @Temp group by Id having Count(Id) = 1
)and ProductId in(
    select ProductId from @Temp group by ProductId having Count(ProductId) = 1
)
```

Second Query

```
Select * from @Temp
where Id in (
    select Id from @Temp group by Id having Count(Id) > 1
)or ProductId in(
    select ProductId from @Temp group by ProductId having Count(ProductId) > 1
)
```

To see the complete query with output you can check live demo [here](https://rextester.com/ZVY8472).

Comment: Thanks for your input. Output will be correct but sub query with in will be costlier. Looking for  optimum approach to do that as need to run query with huge data.